# How can my SIP PBX pick up incoming cell phone calls?

Tags: android, sip, trunk

My `Android (4.0.4)` phone is a happy `SIP` client of my `(Asterisk) PBX`.

I'm now looking for the opposite, make my cell phone a `SIP trunk`.

The reason for wanting this is that I'd like to be able to receive cell phone calls thru my `PBX`.

While my cell phone recharges I often don't hear it because I'm somewhere else in the office or at home.

If it can register both as a client and a trunk to my PBX, incoming calls could be taken over by the PBX and ring me wherever I am at that moment.

Answer (score -1):

seems a good idea but not sure will it be possible or not

my suggestion is to use  gsm gateway like matrix , goip , .
which will register as sip trunk in astrisk to receive calls from the sim cards